# Vapor 3 - How to populate array property of model from Leaf template form

Tags: swift, forms, vapor, server-side-swift, leaf

I have a **Group**, **User** and an **App** model. Within my Group model, I have a property `var apps: [App]` and I create a sibling relationship bw Group and User.

In my WebsiteController, I have 2 handlers:

1. `createGroupHandler` which handles the **GET** request at **/groups/create**
2. `createGroupPostHandler` which handles the **POST** request at **/groups/create**

My problem is that after selecting app objects in my form in my **createGroup.leaf** template, when I create my new group no apps are being populated into my apps array.

I created structs to represent the context being rendered in my `createGroupHandler` and to handle the data being passed in the post request for `createGroupPostHandler`

```
struct CreateGroupContext: Encodable {
    let title = "Create Group"
    let users: Future<[User]>
    let apps: Future<[App]>
}

struct CreateGroupData: Content {
    let name: String
    let apps: [App]
    let users: [String]?
}
```

The apps are properly loaded into the form but despite selecting them like in the image below, they aren't added to the array [image]

My `createGroupPostHandler` looks like below. **I don't know how to grab the selected apps and populate my `apps: [App]` array when I create my group is my issue**, I feel like this is where I should be doing that, but I don't know how to grab that from the Leaf template.

```
func createGroupPostHandler(_ req: Request, data: CreateGroupData) throws -> Future<Response> {
        let group = Group(name: data.name, apps: data.apps)
        return group.save(on: req).flatMap(to: Response.self) { group in
            guard let id = group.id else {
                throw Abort(.internalServerError)
            }

            var userSaves: [Future<Void>] = []
            for user in data.users ?? [] {
                try userSaves.append(User.addUser(user, to: group, on: req))
            }

            let redirect = req.redirect(to: "/groups/\(id)")
            return userSaves.flatten(on: req).transform(to: redirect)
        }
    }
```

This is what my createGroup.leaf looks like: [image]

Comment: For anyone that ever comes across a similar problem, I decided to just make a **Many-to-Many relationship between App and Group** and create an `addApp` function within my **App** model that attaches a new relationship based on the string typed in the html `<input>` form and the group object passed in (done in Vapor book). I could **not** figure out a way to populate the `var apps: [App]` property declared in my **Group** model.

Answer (score 1):

I use index notation of naming `input` tags in HTML, such as `score[0]`, `score[1]`, etc. Vapor is then quite happy to parse this and create a dictionary (okay, technically not an array!).

Use this notation in the Leaf file:

```
#for(result in results) {
    <input type="text" name="score[#(index)]" value="#(result.score)">
}
```

The controller function:

```
struct SaveResult:Content
{
    var score:[Int:String]
}

func saveRoll(_ request:Request) throws -> Future<View>
{
    return try request.content.decode(SaveResult.self).flatMap
    {
        result in
        for i in 0...(result.score.count) - 1
        {
            print( detail.score[i] )
        }
        return try self.index(request)
    }
}
```